# Trying to put text below an image, the text is way too below

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a bunch of code, but the part that pertains to my question is this:

```css
.red-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.red-column img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class='red-column'>
  <img src="./assets/images/acapulco.jpg" alt="acapulco">
  <h3>Acapulco</h3>
</div>
```

Basically, I am trying to have an image, and below, a text describing what city that image represents.

However, the text appears way too below:

[image]

How can I make the text go up a little bit so it can be seen within the container?

Comment: Have you considered putting the ``<img>`` inside a ``<figure>``, and then using ``<figcaption>`` for the text?  That would certainly be better for semantics and SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely the default margin on the `h3` element. You can override it with a class and set the `margin` to `0`.

```css
.red-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.red-column img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='red-column'>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="acapulco">
  <h3 class='title'>Acapulco</h3>
</div>
```